# Multilabel classification neural network, any one label

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I am trying to figure out to build a neural network in which let's say I have 3 output labels (A, B, C).

Now my data consist of rows in which 2 of the labels can be 1. Like A and B will be 1 and C will be 0. Now I want to train my neural network such that it can predict A or B. I don't want it to be trained to have high probability for both A and B (like multilabel problems), I want only one of them.

The reason for this is that the rows having  1 in A and B are more like don't care rows in which predicting either A or B will be correct. So I don't want neural network to find minima where it tries to predict both A and B.

Is it possible to train neural network like this?

Comment: Your label space consists of 8 distinct sets of labels, from `0 0 0` to `1 1 1`, out of which `1 1 0` and `1 1 1` are don't care cases. Now, in the rest 6 cases, do you care about predicting `A` and `B` both correctly or any one of them consistently over the dataset or just any one of them over the entire order without consistency. For example, if the label is `0 1 0`, do you care if it predicts either `1 1 *` or `0 0 *` or `0 1 *` (* means either 0 or 1). Consistently means given the same example `0 1 0`, on one batch it may predict as `0 0 *` & the next `1 1 *` & next `0 1 *`. Explain this.

Comment: If the label is [0,1,0], then I  would expect the system to predict [0,1,0] correctly as there is only 1 answer. If labels are [1,1,0], then either `[1,*,0]` or `[*,1,0]` will be correct, and no consistency is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using a weight is the best way I can think of for your application.

Define a weight `w` for each sample such that `w = 0` if `A = 1` and `B = 1`, else `w = 1`. Now, define your loss function as:

```
w * (CE(A) +CE(B)) + w' * min(CE(A), CE(B)) + CE(C)
```

where `CE(A)` gives the cross-entropy loss over label `A`. The `w'` indicates complement of `w`. The loss function is quite simple to understand. It will try to predict both `A` and `B` correctly when both `A` and `B` are not `1`. Otherwise, it will either predict `A` or `B` correctly. Remember, which one out of `A` and `B` will be predicted correctly cannot be known in advance. Also, it may not be consistent over batches. Model will always try to predict the class `C` correctly.

If you are using your own weights to indicate sample importance, then you should use multiply the entire above expression with that weight.

However, I wouldn't be surprised if you get similar (or even better) performance with the classic multi-label loss function. Assuming you have equal proportion of each label, then only in 1/8th of cases, you are allowing your network to predict either `A` or `B`. Otherwise, the network has to predict all three of them correctly. Usually, the simpler loss functions work better.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

- a typical network will give you a probability for each class.
- how you interpret it is up to you.
- if you get equal weights in a single label scenario it means both labels are equally likely

The typical implementation for multi class classifier with neural networks is using a softmax layer, with one output per class

if you want a single label classifier, you treat the output with the maximum value as the selected label.
the actual value of this output compared to the others is a measure of the confidence in this value.

in case of equality, it means that both outputs are as likely